# Implementation of the Wilson-Theta Method

Tags: list-manipulation, vector

**Edited version**

I (am a beginner) try to solve a problem in which I have to use some vectors that have specific values for each time step. I thought it would be interesting to define something similar to:

```
dt=1/100;
a1=G/(B*T*dt);
v[0]={{0.02},{0.02},{0.02},{0.02}};
v[t_]:=v[t-1]+ a1 v[t-1];
Plot[v[t][[1]],{t,0,10,dt}]
```

The general context is the implementation of the Wilson-Theta Method for solving a simple structural dynamics problem.

```
m= 20000;
k=18000000;
massmatrix={{m,0},{0,m}};
stiffnessmatrix={{2k,-k },{ -k,k}};
invmass=Inverse[massmatrix];
p[t_]:= 5000000 Sin[2Pi t];
G=1/2;
B=1/6;
T=1.41;
dt=1/100;

v[0]={0.02,0.02};
vdot[0]={0,0};
b=(-(stiffnessmatrix.v[0]));
vdotdot[0]=LinearSolve[massmatrix,b];

a0=1/(B ((T dt)^2));
a1=G/(B T dt);
a2=1/(B T dt);
a3 = 1/(2 B)-1;
a4= G/B -1;
a5= ((G/B)-2) (T dt)/2;
a6=(1-G) dt;
a7 = G dt;
a8= (1/2 - B) dt^2;
a9=B dt^2;

Khat=stiffnessmatrix+a0 massmatrix;
t[0]=0;
t[n_]:=t[n-dt]+dt;
```

Ok until there.

```
A[n_]:=ConstantArray[p[t[n]]+T (p[t[n+dt]]-p[t[n]]),{2,2}];
phat[n_]:=A[n]+massmatrix (a0 v[t[n]]+a2 vdot[t[n]]+a3 vdotdot[t[n]]);

m=n+T;
o= n+1;
phat[m_]:=p[n]+T (p[n+1]-p[n])+massmatrix.(a0 v[n]+a2 vdot[n]+a3 vdotdot[n]);

v[m]=Inverse[smatrix].phat[m];
vdotdot[m_]:=a0 (v[m]-v[m-T])-a2 vdot[m-T] - a3 vdotdot[m-T];
vdotdot[o_]:=vdotdot[o-1]+(1/T) (vdotdot[o-1+T]-vdotdot[o-1]);
vdot[o_]:=vdot[o-1]+ a6 vdotdot[o-1] + a7 vdotdot[o];
v[o_]:= v[o-1]+dt vdot[o-1] + a8 vdotdot[o-1]+ a9 vdotdot[o];
```

My problem is that I don't know to manage the increment correctly. Ideally, I would like to create a function `phat[(n+T)_]:=...` but I don't know how to deal with it.
The goal is to find the displacements `v[n]` for each time step.

Do you have any idea to help me please?
Thank you to all of you for your answers.

Comment: Could you be more descriptive of what you wish to achieve?  Since your code is the only guideline, but it doesn't work as written, there is not much to go by.

Comment: Maybe you mean recursive definition: `RSolve[{v[t] == (1 + a1) v[t - 1], v[0] == v0}, v, t]` gives `(1 + a1)^t v0` for `v[t]`.

Answer (score 2):

There are some *free* parameters in the example code so in what follows there will be some creative *interpretation* of what constitutes the essence of the problem.

Like **@Alx** points out in the comments section, `v` seems to be a recursive definition that is not operational in the form provided in the *Q*.

Using [*`RSolve`*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) to solve for the unknown function `v`

```
{rsol} = RSolve[{v[t + 1] == (1 + a1) v[t], v[0] == v0}, v[t], t]
```

we obtain

> ```
> {{v[t] -> (1 + a1)^t v0}}
> ```

Notice how the provided solution depends on `t` and `v0` but it also depends on `a1`; `a1` in turn seems to be dependent on the *free* parameters `dt`, `G`, `B`and `T`.

In the following code we'll define some constants that will prove useful in the subsequent definition of the `v` function:

```
(* desired number of vector components *)
n = 4;

(* selected initial value for *all* components *)
vj0 = 0.02;

(* vector of initial values *)
v0 = ConstantArray[vj0, n];
```

If different vector components need different initial values, perhaps the easier way to go about is to hand-code them eg `v0 = {0.01, 0.04, 0.03, 0.07}` for a $4$-component vector; more complicated initial conditions could probably benefit from using [*`Table`*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html).

```
 (* vt is a representation of the *body* the vector-valued function *)
 (*   we still need to take into account how a1 is defined *)
 vt = v[t] /. rsol
```

> ```
> {0.02 (1 + a1)^t, 0.02 (1 + a1)^t, 0.02 (1 + a1)^t, 0.02 (1 + a1)^t}
> ```

In what follows, we'll provide some random values for the free parameters and define the vector-valued function `v`:

```
(* provide values for the free parameters in a1 *)
G = 6.674 10^-1;
B = 5;
T = 273.15;

With[{G = G, B = B, T = T, v0 = v0, n0 = n},

 (* NumericFunction might be not necessary for the purpose at hand... *)
 (* Listable helps thread the function over lists of arguments *)

 SetAttributes[v, {NumericFunction, Listable}];

 (* use a default value for the parameter representing the desired number of vector components *)
 Default[v, 7] = n0;

 (* use Evaluate on the rhs of SetDelayed to force the repacement of a1 *)
 (*   with its corresponding formula *once* *)

 (* otherwise function v would perform the replacement *every* time it is *)
 (*   evaluated, instead of just once during its definition *)
 v[t_, dt_, G_: G, B_: B, T_: T, v0_: v0, n0_.] := Evaluate[vt /. a1 -> G/(B T dt)]

]
```

After this point, we have a vector-valued function that evaluates into numbers; as a trivial example: `v[0, 0.02]` evaluates to `{0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02}`.

Next, we are going to define some functions that will assist us in displaying the requested plots.

```
vTemporalData[tRange_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &), dt_?NumericQ, vargs___] := 

  Module[{n, ts, vs, tdargs, n0, cnames},

    (* depending on the supplied range, actual step-size might be slightly bigger than the supplied dt *)
    n = Ceiling[Total[tRange {-1, 1}]/dt];
    ts = N[Array[# &, n, tRange]];

    (* function v evaluated over ts *)
    vs = v[ts, dt, vargs];

    (* take advantage of the defined Default value for the desired number of vector components *)
    n0 = Default[v, 7];
    cnames = FromCharacterCode /@ (97 + Range[n0] - 1);

    (* providing a list with "ComponentNames" is not necessary *)
    (*   the individual vector component data could also be extracted by using integer indexes *)
    (*   eg '1' for the first, '2' for the second etc *)
    tdargs = {
      ValueDimensions -> n0,
      "MetaInformation" -> {"ComponentNames" -> cnames}
     };

    (* define a TemporalData object to store the values of the vector-valued function *)
    TemporalData[vs, {ts}, Apply[Sequence][tdargs]]

 ]
```

The actual plotting function is:

```
Options[vPlot]={"DisplayLayout"->"Distinct"};

vPlot::optnerr="Unknown option value '`1`' for Option \"DisplayLayout\". Available option values include \"Together\" and \"Distinct\".";

(* assuming tRange[[1]] < tRange[[-1]] *)
vPlot[tRange_?(VectorQ[#,NumericQ]&),dt_?NumericQ,vargs___,OptionsPattern[]]:=

  Module[{cnames,td,pltTogether,pltDistinct},

    (* get the values of the vector-valued function *)
    td=vTemporalData[tRange,dt,vargs];

    (* get the arbitrary names of the vector components *)
    cnames=td["ComponentNames"];

    (* plot functions used to assemble output *)
    pltTogether[series_,names_]:=
      DateListPlot[series,
        PlotLegends->LineLegend[Automatic,names,LegendLabel->Row[{"Vector components",":"}]]];

     pltDistinct[series_,names_]:=Map[
        DateListPlot[series["PathComponent",#],
          FrameLabel->{{None,None},{None,Row[{"Vector component",":"," ",#}]}}]&,
       names];

    (* output selector *)
    Which[
      (* plot all the components in one graph *)
      OptionValue["DisplayLayout"]==="Together",pltTogether[td,cnames] ,

      (* or, plot the components in distinct graphs *)
      OptionValue["DisplayLayout"]==="Distinct",pltDistinct[td,cnames],

      (* on error... *)
      True,Message[vPlot::optnerr,Evaluate[OptionValue["DisplayLayout"]]]
     ]

]
```

Finally, we are able to plot the vector-valued function in a single plot

```
vPlot[{0, 100}, 0.01, "DisplayLayout" -> "Together"]
```

> [image]

or we can plot each component in a separate plot

```
vPlot[{0, 100}, 0.01, "DisplayLayout" -> "Distinct"]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps. Merry x-mas, happy holidays if any of this applies :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define functions that contain vectors directly, almost as you have it:

```
dt = 1/100;
a1 = G/(B*T*dt);
v[0] = {0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05};
v[t_] := v[t - 1] + a1 v[t - 1];
```

Now you can directly query the v[ ]s for the terms you wish. For example:

```
v[1]
{0.02 + (2. G)/(B T), 0.03 + (3. G)/(B T), 0.04 + (4. G)/(B T), 0.05 + (5. G)/(B T)}
```

Use Map (shortcut /@) to get the first three terms:

```
v /@ Range[3]
```